# Install brackets on fedora linux 24

Tags: fedora, software-installation

How to install brackets in fedora 24
I want install one IDE for web programming(client)
I use brackets in windows and i want install it in fedora

Answer (score 4):

```
$ sudo yum install yum-plugin-copr
$ sudo yum copr enable mosquito/brackets
$ sudo yum update
$ sudo yum install brackets
```

And that should be you.

Answer (score 2):

For `dnf` use the following commands

```
sudo dnf copr enable mosquito/brackets 
sudo dnf install brackets
```